# Object optimization and grouping

Tags: c#, object, optimization, entity-framework-6

I have objects that are defined this way:

```
class BFull
{
    public string ImageID { get; set; }
    public List<string> Tapes { get; set; }
}

class OptSet
{
    public int SetID { get; set; }
    public List<string> Tapes { get; set; }
    public List<string> Images { get; set; }
}
```

The BFull object is DB defined and I can't alter it much. The second one is the wanted result of my actions. And the problem is:

I need to optimize those BFulls into OptSets with a limitation that any given OptSet can have max 24 distinct tapes and consist only complete BFulls. Can anybody help how to achieve that?

Comment: How is `BFull` related to `OptSet`? Do you mean `1:n` relationship?

Comment: An `n:1` to relationship. Any BFull can exist inside only one OptSet, but one OptSet can have many BFulls in it. I should problaly change the OptSet definition to have only a `List<BFull> FullBackups {get; set;}` field.

Comment: In what respect should the sets be optimised?

Comment: So maybe write custom setter and limit the number of `BFull`s to 25? Sorry not quite sure what you want to optimise.

Comment: The goal is to have as little OptSets as possible. I've got a tape library that can accept only 24 tapes at a time an I need to optimize it to the point where I have the fewest number of sets of 24 tapes that will give me the biggest number of backups at a time.

Comment: 'Fewest number of sets of 24 tapes' this seems trivial - if you have 50 tapes, then you'll have 3 sets (24+24+2)?

Comment: It's not so trivial at all. I haven't done well at explaining the issue. `BFull` is a full backup image that maybe on only one tape but maybe on maximum 24 tapes. Any given tape can contain exactly one or more backup image parts. This is why i need to check for max 24 DISTINCT tapes and only complete backup images. That said, an example: Tapes 1 to 24 can contain more than 24 backup images.